# Asking about a method for solving a problem in a larger program - On topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I would like to ask a question about dealing with a unique requirement in an app I'm developing. I want to know what method could solve the problem, given **X**, **Y** and **Z** constraints/requirements.

**Is asking for the pseudo-code or method of solving the problem on topic?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be on-topic. All of the requirements and design, including the design of data structures and algorithms, is on-topic here.